# How to convert from xmlview to jsview in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am currently working on Proof of concept on fiori application, i currently have a fiori application as a reference which has a xml view representation, I am pretty much sure of writing the logic in js view. Is there a way to convert a xml view to javascript view in sapui5. Please advice.

regards,
Nagarjun

Comment: I don't think there is an automated way of going from something structured as XML to something as unstructured as Javascript... but why would you convert to JS in the first place?

Comment: **_JS View_ is now deprecated** (since 1.90). Consider using _[Typed View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0)_ instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to struggle as you're moving from a declarative to an imperative definition type. It's not impossible but I don't know of any automated way.

But also, as @qualiture said, why would you want to do this anyway? Assuming you expect your Fiori application to be supported by folks other than yourself, defining the views in anything other than XML is asking for trouble, as most Fiori developers conversant with UI5 would expect to find the views in XML.